# Wpf providing data from web to different parts of application

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application that gets data from a web-server.

It contains two Views

- `LeftView`
- `RightView`

three Models

- `LeftModel`
- `RightModel`
- `CentralModel`

and two ViewModels

- `LeftViewModel`
- `RightViewModel`

I will show only `LeftView`, `LeftViewModel`, `LeftModel`, and `CentralModel` (too much code). You can find the entire project [here](https://A191919@bitbucket.org/A191919/wpfapplication139.git).

I guess the main problem is that the `UpdateCollection()` have high coupling with `public ObservableCollection<SomeTypeA> Items {get; set;}`.

Therefore I have the feeling that I cannot place `UpdateCollection()` in `CentralModel`.

I think it will be better if `UpdateCollection()` will be in `CentralModel` how to make that?

Work logic is very simple, incoming message from web server add into `public Dictionary<string, Action<MessageReceivedEventArgs>> Handle { get; set; }`

```
        public void Message(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dresult = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, SomeTypeA>>(e.Message);
        if (Handle.ContainsKey(dresult.Keys.ToList()[0]))
        {
            Handle[dresult.Keys.ToList()[0]](e);
        }
    }
```

, if dictionary contains key, it firing event in model

```
CentralModel.Instance.Handle.Add("central_office", (m) =>
        {
            var dresult = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, SomeTypeA>>(m.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(m.Message.ToString());
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string,SomeTypeA> item in dresult)
            {
                if (!Items.Any(key=>key.ID==dresult["central_office"].ID))
                {
                    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() => Items.Add(item.Value)));
                }
                foreach (SomeTypeA subitem in Items)
                {
                    subitem.ID = item.Value.ID;
                    subitem.Name = item.Value.Name;
                    subitem.Value = item.Value.Value;
                    subitem.Work = item.Value.Work;
                    subitem.Department = item.Value.Department;
                }
            }
        });
```

**ServerClass.cs**

```
namespace Server
{
class ServerClass
{
    private WebSocketServer appServer;

    public void Setup()
    {
        appServer = new WebSocketServer();

        if (!appServer.Setup(2012)) //Setup with listening port
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to setup!");
            Console.ReadKey();
            return;
        }

        appServer.NewMessageReceived += new SessionHandler<WebSocketSession, string>(appServer_NewMessageReceived);

        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        if (!appServer.Start())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to start!");
            Console.ReadKey();
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("The server started successfully! Press any key to see application options.");

        SomeTypeA FirstWorker = new SomeTypeA()
        {
            Department = "Finance",
            ID = "0",
            Name = "John",
            Work = "calculate money"
        };
        SomeTypeB SecondWorker = new SomeTypeB()
        {
            ID = "1",
            Name = "Nick",
            Work = "clean toilet"
        };

        while (true)
        {
            FirstWorker.value += 1;
            SecondWorker.value += 5;
            Dictionary<string, SomeTypeA> Element1 = new Dictionary<string, SomeTypeA>();
            Element1.Add("central_office", FirstWorker);
            Dictionary<string, SomeTypeB> Element2 = new Dictionary<string, SomeTypeB>();
            Element2.Add("back_office", SecondWorker);
            string message1 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Element1);
            string message2 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Element2);

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            foreach (WebSocketSession session in appServer.GetAllSessions())
            {
                session.Send(message1);
                session.Send(message2);
            }
        }
    }

    private void appServer_NewMessageReceived(WebSocketSession session, string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Client said: " + message);
        session.Send("Server responded back: " + message);
    }
}
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
namespace Server
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServerClass myServer = new ServerClass();
        myServer.Setup();
        myServer.Start();
    }
}
}
```

**LeftView.cs**

```
<Grid>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding LM.Items}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding Name}"></Label>
                    <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Work}"></Label>
                    <Label Grid.Column="2" Content="{Binding Value}"></Label>
                    <Label Grid.Column="3" Content="{Binding ID}"></Label>
                    <Label Grid.Column="4" Content="{Binding Department}"></Label>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

**LeftViewModel.cs**

```
namespace WpfApplication139.ViewModels
{
public class LeftViewModel
{
    public LeftModel LM { get; set; }
    public LeftViewModel()
    {
        LM = new LeftModel();
    }
}
}
```

**LeftModel.cs**

```
namespace WpfApplication139.Models
{
public class LeftModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<SomeTypeA> Items {get; set;}
    public LeftModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<SomeTypeA>();
        CentralModel.Instance.Setup("ws://127.0.0.1:2012", "basic", WebSocketVersion.Rfc6455);
        CentralModel.Instance.Start();
        UpdateCollection();
    }

    public void UpdateCollection()
    {
        CentralModel.Instance.Handle.Add("central_office", (m) =>
        {
            var dresult = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, SomeTypeA>>(m.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(m.Message.ToString());
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string,SomeTypeA> item in dresult)
            {
                if (!Items.Any(key=>key.ID==dresult["central_office"].ID))
                {
                    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() => Items.Add(item.Value)));
                }
                foreach (SomeTypeA subitem in Items)
                {
                    subitem.ID = item.Value.ID;
                    subitem.Name = item.Value.Name;
                    subitem.Value = item.Value.Value;
                    subitem.Work = item.Value.Work;
                    subitem.Department = item.Value.Department;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

**CentralModel.cs**

```
namespace WpfApplication139.Models
{
public class CentralModel
{
    private WebSocket websocketClient;

    private string url;
    private string protocol;
    private WebSocketVersion version;

    private static CentralModel instance;

    public Dictionary<string, Action<MessageReceivedEventArgs>> Handle { get; set; }
    private CentralModel()
    {
        Handle = new Dictionary<string, Action<MessageReceivedEventArgs>>();
    }
    public void Setup(string url, string protocol, WebSocketVersion version)
    {
        this.url = url;
        this.protocol = protocol;
        this.version = WebSocketVersion.Rfc6455;

        websocketClient = new WebSocket(this.url, this.protocol, this.version);
        websocketClient.MessageReceived += new EventHandler<MessageReceivedEventArgs>(CentralModel.Instance.Message);
    }
    public void Start()
    {
        websocketClient.Open();
    }
    public static CentralModel Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new CentralModel();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
    public void Message(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dresult = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, SomeTypeA>>(e.Message);
        if (Handle.ContainsKey(dresult.Keys.ToList()[0]))
        {
            Handle[dresult.Keys.ToList()[0]](e);
        }
    }
}
}
```

SomeTypeA and SomeTypeB using for json serealization of two types of messages.

**SomeTypeA.cs**

```
public class SomeTypeA
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Work { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
}
```

**SomeTypeB.cs**

```
public class SomeTypeB
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Work { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this on my phone, so code examples might look rubbish, sorry.

First off, if you're going to use your own classes to define your JSON models, Newtonsoft isn't really needed. That's an extra assembly you have to license correctly. Use the built in JavaScriptSerializer from the assembly

```
System.Web.Extensions
```

If you're going to deserialize the data into a dictionary, just use the built in classes.

Refer to this url for creating classes that can be used to deserialize your JSON data: [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com)

So, with JSON like this

```
{
    "name": "My Name",
    "age": "22",
    "info": {
        "social": [
            "Facebook", "Twitter", "Google+"
        ]
    }
}
```

C# would be like

```
public class Info
{
     public List<string> social { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string age { get; set; }
    public Info info { get; set; }
}

...
RootObject JSON= new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<RootObject>(myJSONData);
...
```

You can then bind the RootObject to your list view and use the different properties in your data binding to get the information.